# Extracting a single value from JSON with JSONPATH selector and mulltiple filters

Tags: json, jsonpath

This seems very much possible, but I can't get it to work. Could be my JSON or my jsonpath selector. Not sure.

Here's the simple JSON showing a book inventory with the cost of 10 and 20 copies, along with which ones are On Sale:

```
{
    "Books": {
        "1": {
            "Title": "Title of the 1st book",
            "Cost": {
                "10": 19.95,
                "20": 29.95
            },
            "OnSale": 0
        },
        "2": {
            "Title": "Title of the 2nd book",
            "Cost": {
                "10": 9.95,
                "20": 39.95
            },
            "OnSale": 1
        },
        "3": {
            "Title": "Title of the 3rd book",
            "Cost": {
                "10": 5.95,
                "20": 49.95
            },
            "OnSale": 0
        }
    },
    "ChosenQuantity": "10" 
}
```

Using the [stefan.goessner jsonpath library](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/), I want the **cost of 10 books that are On Sale** with the following jsonpath selector:

`$.Books[?(@.OnSale==1)].Cost[?($.ChosenQuantity)]`

I can't hard code any of the key values into the jsonpath selector.

With the above jsonpath, what I'm expecting:

```
[
    9.95
]
```

Instead, I'm getting the following:

```
[
    9.95,
    39.95
]
```

To test, I've been using https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/ with the Goessner implementation.

Is the problem in the JSON, the jsonpath selector filters, or both?

Comment: This has nothing to do with xpath; you should remove the tag.

Comment: You're right. Replaced the `xpath` tag with `jsonpath`.

Comment: You cannot do this with jsonpath

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$.Books[?(@.OnSale==1)].Cost.10
```

or (depending on where you test it):

```
$.Books..[?(@.OnSale==1)].Cost.10
```

It should get you the right value.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. You can test it with https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/

Comment: @arzoum Well, that's the problem with json - it depends where you check (which is why xpath is indeed better....); it works on that site under the Goessner tab. Also works here: https://jsonpath.com/.

Comment: Hard coding the "10" into the selector does work. What I'm looking for is the correct syntax for the filter that uses the value of `$.ChosenQuantity` as the key to pull the value for `Cost`.

Comment: Is it supposed to works ? Installed Ruby jsonpath: `jsonpath '$.Books[?(@.OnSale==1)].Cost.10'  file`. I get `[]`

Comment: @GillesQuenot There are several implementations of jsonpath. The one I'm using is called the [Goessner implementation](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)

Comment: @arzoum I'm afraid I couldn't come up with a way to replace the hardcoding of "10" with a value of `$.ChosenQuantity`; I suspect it may be impossible with jsonpath, but will be happy to be corrected.